# Can a Google Cloud Printer send the output to a web service?

Tags: web-services, google-cloud-print

I was wondering if google cloud print can be configured to send to a custom web service. I was thinking about sending documents that need to be OCR'd to my web service to process. Can this be done directly with google cloud print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You'll essentially create a Google Cloud Print printer, in software. When the new print job arrives (a PDF with metadata) then you do whatever you want to with it.

- The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/) is very clear
- Some example code (Go) can be found in the official [Google Cloud Print CUPS Connector](https://github.com/google/cups-connector)
- More example code (Python) can be found in the [Google Cloudprint Proxy](https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint)
- The [GCP Developers mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gcp-developers) is useful